# Mocking a concrete class - It's always null

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to mock a concrete Class using Mockito. However, it remains null in the service under test.

My concrete class and Service:

```
//My Concrete Class
@Component("supporter")
public class Supporter
{
   @Autowired
   private IDriver driver;
   public int someMethod(int){...}
   ...
}

//Service Class that uses this abstract class
public class Service implements IService
{
   private ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;
   @Autowired
   public void setExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler) {
          this.exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
   }

   private Supporter supporter;
   @Autowired
   public void setSupporter(Supporter supporter) {
        this.supporter = supporter;
   }
   public int hookItem(int arg)
   {
      ...
      //supporter is always null while mock testing <----
      int count = supporter.someMethod(arg);
      ...
      return count;
   }
}
```

My Test Code :

```
public class ServiceTest extends AbstractTestMockito
{
    ...
    IService service = null;
    @Mock
    private ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        service = new Service();
    }

    @Test(enabled=true)
    public void shouldDoSomething()
    {
        Supporter supporter = Mockito.mock(Supporter.class);
        given(supporter.someMethod(1)).willReturn(new Integer(10));

        final int response = service.hookItem(1);
        //Assert...
    }
}
```

What could be the reason for it being null?
(My classes/service are Spring beans)

Comment: Where does the `service` variable come from? Also which one is `null`?

Comment: Added 'service' creation (It's in the @BeforeMethod). 'supporter' is null in the Service class (shown in the comment)

Comment: DId you call Mockito.initMocks(this) ?

Comment: Yes, it is done in the AbstractTestMockito class as a @BeforeMethod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the test class, it seems like you you are not injecting the mocked `Supporter` instance into the `service` instance, e.g. try to add `service.setSupporter(supporter);` before calling `service.hookItem(1)`.

Comment: This was it. Thank you. However, I have a follow up question. I have updated my question - I also have an interface ExceptionHandler. Why don't I need to explicitly set it (as it is not null, inside the service)? Is Mockito automatically capable to  injecting the interface mocks?

Comment: Yes, when I read your example and comments, I understand you are using the `@Mock` annotation together with `Mockito.initMocks(this);` You can read more about that (and other features) in the JavaDoc of the [Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mock_annotation) class. Moreover, I wrote a [blog post](http://www.jayway.com/2012/02/25/mockito-and-dependency-injection/) on the subject about a year ago that you may find interesting.